# Как правильно писать программы?

Tags: java, ооп, gui

Все книги по программированию, которые я читал, отлично раскрывают технические детали написания кода. Например, что если в классе-родители есть абстрактные методы, то в классе-наследнике они должны быть переопределены или же этот класс сам должен быть абстрактным. Или дается теория, читал несколько книжек, где были отлично объяснены принципы ООП. Это все очень хорошо и важно. Но ни книги, ни в универе не учат как же писать программы(мое мнение).
Приведу пример:
Я пишу GUI. У меня есть метод, в котором я задаю свойства для JInternalFrame, настраиваю его вид. И потом вызываю этот метод для каждого JInternalFrame. Вот он:

```
private static void createIFrameProperties(JInternalFrame iframe) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    BasicInternalFrameUI ui = new BasicInternalFrameUI(iframe);
    iframe.setUI(ui);
    ((BasicInternalFrameUI) iframe.getUI()).getNorthPane()
            .setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 28));
    ((BasicInternalFrameUI) iframe.getUI()).getNorthPane().setBorder(
            new LineBorder(Color.GRAY, 1));
    ((BasicInternalFrameUI) iframe.getUI()).getNorthPane().remove(0);
    ((BasicInternalFrameUI) iframe.getUI()).getNorthPane().remove(0);
    ((BasicInternalFrameUI) iframe.getUI()).getNorthPane().remove(0);
    ((BasicInternalFrameUI) iframe.getUI()).getNorthPane().revalidate();
    ((BasicInternalFrameUI) iframe.getUI()).getNorthPane().repaint();
    JComponent title = ((BasicInternalFrameUI) iframe.getUI())
            .getNorthPane();
    for (int i = 0; i < title.getComponentCount(); i++) {
        JComponent component = (JComponent) title.getComponent(i);
        if (component instanceof JButton) {
            JButton button = ((JButton) component);
            button.setToolTipText("Закрыть");
            button.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(24, 24));
            button.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    button.setIcon(new ImageIcon("images/closered.png"));
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    button.setIcon(new ImageIcon("images/closeEnd.png"));
                }
            });
            button.setIcon(new ImageIcon("images/closeEnd.png"));
            button.setSelectedIcon(new ImageIcon("images/closeEnd.png"));
            button.setPressedIcon(new ImageIcon("images/closeEnd.png"));
        }
    }
    iframe.addInternalFrameListener(new InternalFrameAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void internalFrameClosed(InternalFrameEvent e) {
            frameForRead = null;
            frameForHelp = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void internalFrameClosing(InternalFrameEvent e) {
            frameForRead = null;
            frameForHelp = null;
        }

    });
}
```

Или же можно создать класс, унаследовать его от JInternalFrame и прописать это все в его конструкторе. Вот так:

```
public class MyJInternalFrame extends JInternalFrame {

private boolean isOpened;

public MyJInternalFrame(String s) {
    super(s, true, true, false, false);
    BasicInternalFrameUI ui = new BasicInternalFrameUI(this);
    setUI(ui);
    ((BasicInternalFrameUI) getUI()).getNorthPane()
            .setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 28));
    ((BasicInternalFrameUI) getUI()).getNorthPane().setBorder(
            new LineBorder(Color.GRAY, 1));
    ((BasicInternalFrameUI) getUI()).getNorthPane().remove(0);
    ((BasicInternalFrameUI) getUI()).getNorthPane().remove(0);
    ((BasicInternalFrameUI) getUI()).getNorthPane().remove(0);
    ((BasicInternalFrameUI) getUI()).getNorthPane().revalidate();
    ((BasicInternalFrameUI) getUI()).getNorthPane().repaint();
    createNorthPanel();
    setVisible(true);
    setMinimumSize(new Dimension(400, 500));
}

private void createNorthPanel() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    JComponent title = ((BasicInternalFrameUI) this.getUI())
            .getNorthPane();
    for (int i = 0; i < title.getComponentCount(); i++) {
        JComponent component = (JComponent) title.getComponent(i);
        if (component instanceof JButton) {
            JButton button = ((JButton) component);
            button.setToolTipText("Закрыть");
            button.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(24, 24));
            button.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    button.setIcon(new ImageIcon("images/closered.png"));
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    button.setIcon(new ImageIcon("images/closeEnd.png"));
                }
            });
            button.setIcon(new ImageIcon("images/closeEnd.png"));
            button.setSelectedIcon(new ImageIcon("images/closeEnd.png"));
            button.setPressedIcon(new ImageIcon("images/closeEnd.png"));
        }
    }
}
```

Тогда в программе можно будет просто создавать объекты этого класса и они уже будут должным образом настроены. Тоже самое касается кнопок и всех других элементов управления. Можно все прописать в одном классе, в котором и создается GUI. Такой класс получится у меня примерно на 3000 строк. Или же можно разносить это на несколько классов(как в примере), тогда главный класс будет уже намного меньше. То есть вопрос в следующем: что лучше, один класс на 3000 строк или 20 на 200 строк каждый(цифры взяты приблизительно)?
P.S. Знаю про паттерны, но это по-моему вопрос из другой области. Скорее мне интересно как писать код более профессионально что ли.

Comment: Анализируйте результат. На быстродействие, на потребление памяти. Проводите эксперименты. Вы думаете, что сейчас выйдет какой-то крутой эксперт и скажет, как правильно писать код? Нет! Читайте чужой код прямо здесь в ответах. Смотрите код больших проектов на GitHub. Эта неуверенность пройдёт с опытом.

Comment: Если коротко, то лучше 20 классов по 200 строк.

Comment: @MichaelPak, Все-таки 20 по 200 лучше? Даже не смотря на то что тут получается 4000 вместо 3000?  А можете объяснить почему? Я вижу одну причину - класс, в котором 3000 строк очень тяжело держать и поддерживать. Я слышал конечно что каждый класс должен отвечать только за одну задачу. Но тут это бы соблюдалось, даже если бы был один класс в 3000. Он хоть был бы и огромен, но выполнял бы всего одну задачу (создание GUI). Так есть ли еще какие то причины в данном случае разносить один класс на 20, кроме улучшения читаемости?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, все-таки шаблоны проектирование как раз то, что Вам нужно. В Вашем случае я бы использовал такой паттерн, как [строитель](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)) ([статья с хабрахабр](http://habrahabr.ru/post/244521/)). Но если после ознакомления Вы все же будете не удовлетворены, то предлагаю почитать [**«Совершенный код»**](http://findbook.ru/search/d0?ptype=4&pvalue=9785750200641&r=0&s=1&viewsize=15&startidx=0) Стива Макконнелла.

Comment: спасибо большое! Про строитель не очень понял, наверное пока еще не хватает опыта в программировании. Но теперь знаю в какую сторону двигаться. Скажите еще пожалуйста, а книга Блоха Effective Java и книга Эйкеля Thinking in java помогают двигаться в этом направлении? В смысле написания более профессионального кода(слышал о них как раз такие отзывы)? Или они тоже акцентируются больше на технических деталях?

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров, предлагаю сперва ознакомится с философией джава Эйкеля (хотя бы с первыми главами, где описываются основы ООП), а потом перейти к [банде четырех](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/31079082/). И не обращайте на такую дурацкую картинку, очень хорошая и понятная книга!

Comment: а что скажите про русский перевод философии java? Слышал разные отзывы. Вообще возможно читать? Или лучше все-таки на английском, не смотря на то что это раза в 3 больше времени займет?

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров, люди перечитывают ее по несколько раз, так как запомнить все сразу невозможно. Так что в первый раз лучше читать на русском. Да и плохих отзывов о переводе я не слышал.

Comment: А банда четырех это же вроде вот эта книга: http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/2457392/ или я путаю?

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров, да, есть эта путаница, сам до конца не разобрался. Но все-таки советую прочитать ту книгу, которую я указал.

Comment: То, что вы советуете, это НЕ книга "банды четырех". Книга "банда четырех" так названа по количеству авторов -- это и есть та книга, ссылку на которую дал @АлександрЕлизаров.